# How to display flash swf file in HTML component in Air application?

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

I create a splash screen in adobe flash professional CS5. I published my swf and html wrapper. when I run html wrapper directly it display the splash screen in web browser. I create a HTML control in Adobe Air using flex builder 4.5. I put the swf and html wrapper in assets folder in air application. when I run Air application, it displays nothing. if I create a dummy html page and reference it in Air application it worked fine. How can I solve this problem, so that HTML control display my splash screen swf file.Thanks

Comment: Are your 'extra' files copied to the bin-debug or bin-release folder upon creating a new build?  I'd check.  There is a setting somewhere in Flash Builder that will move extra files.

Comment: when I published splash.swf file, it only created two files, swf and html file. I put these two files in bin-debug folder. but it did not work.

Comment: >I create a HTML control - wheres your code for this?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: @StephenNYC it works if I release build my air application. but when I launched it from adobe flex builder it show nothing. HTML control is simple. <mx:HTML id="html" width="100%" height="100%"
         location="assets/splash.html"/>

Comment: its possible the app couldnt resolve the location you specified. or maybe its displaying but you have same foreground/background color?

Comment: this is not the case. otherwise it wont't display when I export the release of Air application. it shows the wrapper html backgound color but does not play the animation. wrapper html and swf file are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you should need the 'wrapper' html is to display a .swf inside a web browser. As you are developing an Air application, you may load your .swf directly to the Air app using a ModuleLoader.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!-- modules/MySimplestModuleLoader.mxml --> 
<s:Application xmlns:fx="ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"; xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"> 
    <s:ModuleLoader url="MyOther.swf"/>   
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I have HTML control as I coded in question comment. it works fine if I release build my air application.